# Does bounded sequence imply bounded series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

There is a confusing point  in  the  proof  of  $$R=lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \left|{a_k}\over {a_{k+1}}\right|$$  where  $R$  is the  radius  of  convergence  of  the  series  $\Sigma_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k $
 Calling  the  limit  $L$ , 
The technique  is  to  show $$L\le R \ \ \ , R\le L$$  hold  simulteniously .

I  understand  the $L\ge R$  part  .  For  the  other  part , let  some $r\lt L$ . Then , say  for  $k\ge N$ ; $$\left|a_k\over a_{k+1}\right|\gt r\\or,\ \ \left|a_k\right|\gt r\left|a_{k+1}\right| \\and,\ \ \ \left|a_N\right|r^N\ge \left|a_{N+1}\right|r^{N+1}\ge  \left|a_{N+2}\right|r^{N+2}............... $$
So the sequence $\{|a_k|r^k\}$ is eventually  bounded.

Now , if  this  implies  that  the  series  $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k r^k\lt \infty$  then  I  could  say $r\le R$ and  thus  conclude  $L\le R$ . But  the  problem  is **:**

**can  the  boundedness  of  the  sequence $\{|a_k|r^k\}$   imply $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k r^k\lt \infty  ?$**

Answer (score 3):

In general, it does not. But if the sequence $|a_k|r_0^k$ is bounded for some fixed $r_0 > 0$, then the series
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k r^k
$$
converges for $0 \le |r| < r_0$. (For $|r| < r_0$, the sequence tends to $0$ exponentially fast; compare with a geometric series to get convergence.)

Comment: A  proof  would  really  help.  or  at  least  give  some  hints  as  to  how  to  prove  this  result.

Comment: I thought "compare with a geometric series" was a hint: $$|a_k r^k| = |a_k r_0^k| \cdot \left| \frac{r}{r_0} \right|^k \le M  \left| \frac{r}{r_0} \right|^k $$